# Is it possible to select multiple variables with LINQ without using keyword new?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

Is there any way to select both a and b without new keyword in the following code ?

```
(from a in Enumerable.Range(1, 9)
from b in Enumerable.Range(1, 9) select a,b).ToArray();
```

**EDIT** 
My goal was to avoid renaming like new {ax = a, bx = b}

Comment: No you can't. Why don't you want to use the `new`? And what whould be the expected result of your opration? 1,1,2,2,3,3,...,9,9?

Comment: Why do you need this? Well, multiple values must be in a collection or in a class/struct object. How do you want the result to be?

Comment: @namesv Just to avoid renaming variables like new {ax = a, bx = b} results should be same as using the new keyword..

Comment: why do you  want to rename them? By the way `select new {a,b}` works too...

Comment: @namesv thanks that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the tuple class also and you won't have to specify variables

```
 IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> c = (from a in Enumerable.Range(1, 9)
                                          from b in Enumerable.Range(1, 9)
                                          select new Tuple<int, int>(a, b));
```